# how to add class picture to ul who have more than 10 li

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want add class picture768 or class picture1024 with jquery to ul who have class dropdown-menu and has children (li) more than 10 
but this code add class to all ul with class dropdown-menu
i want only add  class picture768 or class picture1024 to ul who has more than 10 li 
please help me

```js
var ct = $('.dropdown-menu').children().size();
setclass(ct); 
function setclass($screensize)
{ 
 if ($(window).width() > 1024) 
 {  
  if(ct>10)
  {   
   $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('picture1024');
   $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('picture768');
  }
 }
 else if($(window).width() > 768 && $(window).width() <= 1024)
 {
  if(ct>10)
  {
   $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('picture768');
   $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('picture1024');
  }
 }  
 else
 {  
  $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('picture768');
  $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('picture1024');  
 }    
}
```

```css
.picture1024
{   
 display:none;
 box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
 border-radius:3px;         
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#FFF !important;
 background-image:url(../img/menu-bg2.jpg);
 background-size:contain;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center bottom;   
 padding-bottom:120%;
 z-index:100;
 width:900%;
 li
 {
  &:hover
  {
   >a
   {
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:$alizarin !important;
   }
  }
  a
  {
   color:#000 !important;
  }
  width:25%;
  float:right;
 }
}
.picture768
{   
 display:none;
 box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
 border-radius:3px;         
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#FFF !important;
 background-image:url(../img/menu-bg2.jpg);
 background-size:contain;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center bottom;   
 padding-bottom:120%;
 z-index:100;
 width:700%;
 li
 {
  &:hover
  {
   >a
   {
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color:$alizarin !important;
   }
  }
  a
  {
   color:#000 !important;
  }
  width:33%;
  float:right;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li> <a href="">product</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>    
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="">3</a></li>
<li><a href="">4</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"> contact
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of if(ct>10), it would be something similar to this:

```
if ($('ul.dropdown-menu li').length >= 11) {
  $("ul.dropdown-menu").addClass("picture1024");
  $("ul.dropdown-menu").removeClass("picture768");
}else
{       
  $('ul.dropdown-menu').removeClass('picture768');
  $('ul.dropdown-menu').removeClass('picture1024');     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when you're calling

```
$('.dropdown-menu').addClass('picture768')
```

you're setting that class on all .dropdown-menu elements. What you probably want is to call setclass on each .dropdown-menu element; something like

```
$('.dropdown-menu').each(setclass())
```

and then do

```
$(this).addClass('picture768')
```

within setclass.  Or just

```
$('.dropdown-menu').each(function() {

   if ($(this).children('li').size() > ...) { 
     addClass...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made this for you, it worked here:

```
function yourNewFunction(){ //cool name, eh?
    var uls = document.getElementsByTagName("ul"); //gets all the ul's from the page
    for(var x = 0; x < uls.length; x++)
    {
        var ulX = uls[x];
        if(hasClass(ulX.className,"dropdown-menu"))//check if have the class 'dropdown-menu'
        {
            var child = ulX.getElementsByTagName("li"); //get all the li's inside the ul
            ulX.className += (child.length > 10)?" picture768":" picture1024"; //add properly the desired class to your list
        }
    }
}

function hasClass(classeString, classe) //function to check if has the desired class into the object
{
    var classes = classeString.split(" ");
    for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) { if(classes[x] == classe) { return true;  }}
    return false;
}
```

You just need to call `yourNewFunction()` and it will work, put it where it pleases you, like into the `body onload` event.